# I am trying to replace an EXIST because its inefficient, but I am coming up with different results. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, case, exists

So I have this query that runs an exist statement, but then when I went to replace it, it didn't return the same number of values for 'Suspended with Audit, EIC Watch'
It actually returned less.

The old portion of code is in the comments, the new code is directly after it.

```
SELECT  t.flngKey AS flngTaskKey,
    t.fstrAccountType,
    t.fstrTaskSource,
    CASE    t.fstrCategory 
        WHEN    '' THEN '' 
        ELSE    t.fstrTaskSource + '_CAT_' + t.fstrCategory 
    END AS fstrCategory,
```

This is the old portion

```
CASE
        --WHEN t.fstrType = '' THEN '' 
        --WHEN wd.fstrWorkType  = 'SUSIN1'
        --AND   wd.fstrOwner        =  ' ' 
        --AND   wd.flngworkkey      =  wr.flngworkkey 
        --AND   wr.fstrAccountType  <> '007' 
        --AND   wr.fblnOpen         =  1 
        --AND Exists
        --  (SELECT 1 
        --  FROM    tblIndicator id
        --  WHERE   id.fstrIndicator   = 'EIWTCH' 
        --  AND id.flngVer=0    
        --  --AND   fdtmCease       > @pdtmRunDate 
        --  AND id.flngAccountKey  = wd.flngAccountKey)
        --THEN 'Suspended for Audit Indicator - EIC Watch For'
        --ELSE  t.fstrTaskSource + '_TYP_' + t.fstrType 
        --END AS fstrType,
```

This is the new

```
CASE
WHEN t.fstrType = '' THEN '' 
    WHEN wd.fstrWorkType    = 'SUSIN1'
    AND wd.fstrOwner        =  ' ' 
    AND wd.flngworkkey      =  wr.flngworkkey 
    AND wr.fstrAccountType  <> '007' 
    AND wr.fblnOpen         =  1 
    AND id.fstrIndicator   = 'EIWTCH' 
    AND id.flngVer=0
    AND id.flngAccountKey  = wd.flngAccountKey
    THEN 'Suspended for Audit Indicator - EIC Watch For'
    ELSE    t.fstrTaskSource + '_TYP_' + t.fstrType 
    END AS fstrType,
```

the last part is the same for both (i know its kind of redundant)

```
FROM    tblTaskOpen t with (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWorkDetail wd
    ON t.flngKey=wd.flngWorkKey LEFT OUTER JOIN tblIndicator id
    ON t.flngAccountKey=id.flngAccountKey AND id.fstrIndicator='EIWTCH' AND id.flngVer=0, 
    tblWorktoReturn wr with (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReturn r with (nolock) 
ON  wr.flngReturnKey  = r.flngReturnKey 
AND r.flngVer        = 0,
    t2                      


WHERE   t.fstrCategory   = 'RTNCOR' 
AND wr.flngWorkKey    = t.flngKey 
AND t.fstrCategory   = t2.fstrCategory 
AND t.fstrType       = t2.fstrType
```

In either case, I ended up setting fstrIndicator to the EIWTCH and also flngVer to 0, which should limit the number of records that join with "t" anyways.

What is going on in this EXISTS that is returning more records?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Those two queries are not the same. First of all, you're using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `tblTaskOpen t` and `tblWorkDetail wd`. This will return only those records from `tblWorkDetail wd` that meet `t.flngKey=wd.flngWorkKey` (and all other records from `tblTaskOpen t` but that is not important here).

So the old query has `EXISTS` which doesn't reference `tblTaskOpen t` at all.  It means it checks existence for even those records in `tblWorkDetail wd` that are not eventually returned. Hence this `EXISTS` may return true for more records that straight checking columns of in the new query.